# Android thread questions

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm building an android app where I basically implement a music player from a web content provider. 
In a nutshell, I have a player, with "play", "pause", "stop" playing. At the same time I am using a new thread to provide progress information on a seek bar, and textView with length, and time played.

I would like to ask your advice on the best aproach on threading. I'd like to pause the thread when paused is pressed, stop it when stop is pressed and resume/start it when play is pressed.

I have something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        while(!finished && !stopped)
        {//Do some action on Views...}}
```

And even so, will the thread be completely dead when I leave my app? Won't it be still running?

Thank you very much, and sorry if this is answered elsewhere.

Comment: When you leave your app, if you don't using stop condition, it still alive for a while.

Comment: I guess the only way to stop the thread is to set a boolean on the condition. And leaving the app, set also this boolean, on the onActivityDestroy. Also, I can only assume it's not possible to pause the thread. So a pause on the music, won't pause the thread. But assuming all care is handled properly, the thread will have to stop sometime, thanks to the condition.

Comment: try this to your onDestroy
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Handler+Broadcast in my mediaPlayerDemo.
The MediaPlayer runs in a **Service** and use **handler.post(runnable)** to make a circle.
In Runnable I **sendBroadcast()** and change the textView when **onReceive** in my Activity

```
public void sendToUpdate() {
    // handler
    if (progressHandler == null) {
        progressHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };
    }
    progressHandler.removeCallbacks(progress);
    progressHandler.post(progress);
}

Runnable progress = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mp != null) {
            musicCurrentTime = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            musicLength = mp.getDuration();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent
                    .setAction("com.cookie.media.MUSIC_UPDATE");
            intent.putExtra("musicCurrentTime", musicCurrentTime);
            intent.putExtra("musicId", musicId);
            intent.putExtra("musicLength", musicLength);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        progressHandler.removeCallbacks(progress);
        progressHandler.postDelayed(progress, 1000);
    }
};
```

Like this
You can add **if(mp.isPlaying){}** to avoid consume when the mediaplayer pause or stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
> I would like to ask your advice on the best aproach on threading.
```

May be a look at the official [media player tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html helps